# Set header with logo and navbar inside div with width: max-content to fit on the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one div with `width: max-content` which contents everything and goes beyond the window size.

I would like to put inside that `.pageWrapper` another `div .page-header` which should have on the left of the page ***logo*** and on the right ***menu navbar***. And it should be **sticky** so when I scroll horizontally to the right the elements of the page-header stays sticky.

My problem is that *"menu navbar"* in this case won't be visible on the page. They only be at the end of the right side of the page, which is goes beyond the window size.

How to set `.page-header` width so that "menu navbar" will stay on the right side of the window and be responsive (always stays at the right if page will be resized) ?

```css
<div class="pageWrapper">
    <div class="page-header">
            <div class="logoHeader"></div>
            <div class="nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
        //.. some big table
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is some example how it looks like right now:

Jsfidlle: https://jsfiddle.net/ku1jprbz/

Comment: I think in .pageWrapper class you set with max-content it is the issue try to remove and check navbar working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the navbar to have the screen width you can try to use vw for the width.

```
.pageWrapper {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the problem in this case that sticky header disappears if I scroll way to far right. Any solution how to fix header and allow scrolling horizontally without affecting it ?